# Increment VALUE column in raster in ArcGIS using ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster

I would like to increment the VALUE field in a raster by a constant amount (say 100).

I can do this by using reclassification, but wondering if there is a simpler more direct method (using ArcPy)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use any python, why not simply use the [PLUS](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000096000000.htm) tool to added 100, if you want to multiply the value by 100 then use the [TIMES](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Times/009z0000009p000000/) tool?

Comment: Using Python as the question poster suggested we use Python. I'm interpreting the question as "I have a raster and I want to reclass all values to incremented groups of width 100" - Is the poster trying to add or multiply existing raster values?

Comment: Yeah it's a question asking about python but they have tagged it with `desktop`. If this is a one time process they could use the tools I suggested or if it is part of a larger python solution they could call these tools. If they read the code section for the help on these tools they would see how to call them in a python script. Ultimately it's not exactly clear what they intend.

Comment: Super helpful ty! ArcGIS tools work fine since I can use them with ArcPy in a script. Sorry for the confusing question, I added the python tag because I want to use ArcPy

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly - I'm thinking you could achieve something similar to a reclassify operation programmatically (in arcpy) using some combination of the [Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) and [Numpy Array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) objects, and [associated helper functions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm).

There is probably a better way to do this, but in short you would create an ndarray from your raster dataset, apply some indexing commands to conditionally replace the raster cell values (essentially reclassifying the values), and then finally convert your reclassified ndarry back to an ESRI raster:

```
import arcpy

numpy_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(r'X:\PathTo\MyRasterDataset.jpg')

# for example, reclass all cell values higher than 100 to 1
numpy_array[numpy_array>100] = 1

# then, write this numpy_array back out as a permanent ESRI raster on disk:
out_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(numpy_array)
```

If you're in an ArcMap session, the out_raster should show up in your table of contents after the NumpyArrayToRaster tool finishes.